# How do I read one row of my input text file into multiple rows in a data.frame?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a text file with lines like

```
1600Q   WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14
1700R   BUCKETS=25|PAILS=20|BASKETS=6
```

into a dataframe like

```
1600Q   WASHERS 10
1600Q   FLAT WASHERS    14
1700R   BUCKETS 25
1700R   PAILS   20
1700R   BASKETS 6
```

Using

```
raw.data <- read.table("myData.txt",sep="\t",fill=TRUE, header=FALSE,quote = "")
```

my rows look like

```
1600Q   WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14
1700R   BUCKETS=25|PAILS=20|BASKETS=6
```

Is there a way to split as I read?

Comment: Please provide more than 2 record... I mean does your text go on like this 
`1600Q   WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14|WASHERS=11|FLAT WASHERS=15|WASHERS=12|FLAT WASHERS=16` 
or 
`1600Q   WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14
1601Q   WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14`

Answer (score 0):

Building on agstudy's suggestions, here's how I would process each row of the input file, which I would read in with `read.table` , assuming the only whitespace is between "1600Q" and the list of parts. If there are other whitespaces, you'll have to adjust.
The lines below can be compacted, but this shows in detail the steps taken.

```
# make a fake pair of strings, assuming no other tab separators in file
indat <- c('1600Q' , 
         'WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14|WASHERS=11|FLAT WASHERS=15|WASHERS=12|FLAT WASHERS=16')
pairs  <- unlist(strsplit(indat[2],'[|]'))
outcol <- matrix(nr=length(pairs),nc=2)
for(j in 1:length(pairs) ) {
    outcol[j,] <- unlist(strsplit(pairs[j],"=") )
    }
finalmat <- cbind(rep(indat[1],nrow(outcol)),outcol)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here one way :

```
ll <- strsplit(gsub('([A-Z])[  ]+','\\1=',
          ' 1600Q   WASHERS=10|FLAT WASHERS=14'),'[|]')

read.table(text=unlist(ll),sep='=')

##       V1      V2 V3
## 1  1600Q WASHERS 10
## 2   FLAT WASHERS 14
```

1. make the same separator `=` for each row using regex
2. separate rows using `strsplit`
3. read the all using `read.table`

Comment: Close but not what he wants: he wants the "1600Q" repeated in first column, so you'll have to "save" the ID, then split the row by as many "|" as there are to identify how many output rows there'll be, and finally split by "="

Comment: @CarlWitthoft feel free to edit :) otherwise I will delete this silly answer !